# Azure App Service での Sesston Timeout管理

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

Azure App ServiceでASP.NET Core MVCをリリースします。
IIS上でホストする場合でいう、Session Timeoutおよび、Process Recycleはどのようにして設定できるでしょうか？

Process Recycleは１日１回固定時間に行い、Session Timeoutを1440分に設定することで、Process Recycle時にしかセッションが切れない設定をしたいと考えています。

Azure App ServiceはDockerコンテナを利用しておらず、OSはWindowsを選択しています。

Comment: 「セッションが切れない」とはどういうことを言ってますか？　独自認証システムを実装していて、それに Session を使っていて、Session のデータでユーザーがログインしているか否かを判断している？　で、Session が Timeout してデータが削除されるとユーザー認証に失敗するので困るということ？

Comment: ご指摘の通りです。セッションにユーザー情報があるうちはログイン中の扱いということになります。例えば、標準だと20分でセッションタイムアウトするためログアウト状態になってしまいますが、システム利用方法の関係から、もっと長い時間ログインしっぱなしでないと使いづらいということになります。

Comment: であれば、ワーカープロセスのリサイクルは関係なくて、Session の Timeout の時間（Core は IdleTimeout）を延ばすだけで済むのではないですか。（セキュリティとパフォーマンスの問題は置いとくとしてですが）

Comment: 後出しになってしまってすみません。セッションがインプロセスの場合ですと、プロセスのリサイクルでセッションがクリアされてしまうため、セッションタイムアウト前にリサイクルが走るとセッションタイムアウトと同じ状況となります（IISの場合）。Azureではここに関してどのような設定を行えばよいかを理解しておりません。

Comment: 言ってることが分かりません。何か矛盾しているような気がするのですが。ワーカープロセスがリサイクルされて InProc の Session データが消えるのは何ともできないです。だからワーカープロセスのリサイクルは関係ないと言ったのです。ユーザーには再度ログインしてもらって Session にログインデータを再度保持する他にやることはないと思うのですが？

Comment: ワーカプロセスのリサイクルでInProcのSessionデータが消えるのは理解しています。ですので、システムを利用していない時間帯にリサイクルするタイミングをコントロールしたいということになります。IISでは例えば、システムを利用していない時間帯（夜中の1:00など1日1回）にリサイクルを行うような設定をすることで対応していましたが、Azureではどのようにしてそれを実現できるか知りたいということになります。

Comment: 話が変わってきてませんか？　質問には Session とかその Timeout とかいろいろ書いてありますが、それは何も関係なくて、要するに知りたいのは、「IISでは例えば、システムを利用していない時間帯（夜中の1:00など1日1回）にリサイクルを行うような設定をすることで対応していましたが、Azureではどのようにしてそれを実現できるか」ということだってのですか？　であれば最初からそれだけ書いてもらえていたらと思います。紛らわしい

Comment: 紛らわしい書き方だったようですみません。目的としては、最初に書いた通り1日1回のセッション切れで抑えるための設定を探しています。オンプレミスのIIS時代（inproc）では、プロセスのリサイクルとセッションタイムアウトを意識する必要があったため、それを記載したつもりでした。

Comment: azure app service iis recycle などをキーワードにググるとかしてみましたか？ まだならやってみましょう。できないという記事がヒットします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure App Service上でインプロセスのセッションを用いた場合、Session Timeoutの設定を行っても、プロセスの再起動はコントロールできないため、セッションが消えるタイミングをコントロールすることはできない。

インプロセスでの運用はあきらめ、Redis, Cosmos DB, SQL Serverなどをセッションストアとして用いるのが良い。

そもそもCloudという性質上、Azure上でのセッション管理は上記のようなプロセスに依存しないセッションストアを用いるべき。
ASP.NET Core MVCであれば、Startup.csのConfigureService()メソッド内でセッション用の分散キャッシュを定義するだけでセッションストアを切り替えられる。

```cs
    // SQL Serverをセッションストアとして用いる例
    services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        options.SchemaName = "dbo";
        options.TableName = "SQLSessions";
    });
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60 * 24);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    });
```

Comment: 「IISでは例えば、システムを利用していない時間帯（夜中の1:00など1日1回）にリサイクルを行うような設定をすることで対応していましたが、Azureではどのようにしてそれを実現できるか」という質問ではなかったのですか？　何だか話がいろいろ変わって迷走しているような感じですけど？

Comment: ユーザー認証とセッションの話に戻ってしまったようですが、そもそもユーザー認証にセッションを使うというのが問題で、Session Timeout やワーカープロセスのリサイクルの影響を受けないような認証方式を使うべきだと思いますけど。テンプレートで「個別のアカウント」を選ぶと自動的に実装される ASP.NET Core Identity のようなクッキーベースの認証方式とか。

Comment: もう一つ、コメントしておきます。この記事→ http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2020/06/29/web-server-used-in-aspnet-core-application.aspx の上の方にある図を見てください。Windows を使うそうですので、IIS でホストすると思いますが、ホスティングモデルによっては IIS のワーカープロセスのリサイクルの Session への影響は異なるるように思えます。

Comment: WebSurferさん、色々とキーワード及び情報をありがとうございます。WebSurferさんが何を問題視しているかうまく理解できておりません。その原因は私の持つ知識とWebSurferさんの持つ知識にギャップがありすぎるため（もちろん私の知識が足りないという意味です）、ベース部分での食い違いが起こっているものと思います。いただいたキーワードを勉強した上で理解していこうと思います。